# Security concept for a wiki-like application

Tags: security, user-experience

I created a wiki-like application. Currently, there is no security, so all the contents have "edit"-buttons where the user can edit everything. Now, I want my application to have a public read-only access and the read/write access to edit content.

First of all, I think it is useful to do that with two roles: viewer and editor. For editors, there has to be an authentication mechanism etc..

But then, I see two ways:

1. Make an "editors portal" and a "viewers portal". Editors portal is an admin-like interface for good editing. Viewers portal is good for just reading.
2. Make just one portal for read-access, but when the user is an editor, there is something like an Editing-Layer on top of that. E.g. additional "Edit"-Buttons or mouseover-hint-buttons...something like that.

The 2-portals solution seems to be common for me. Do you have any experiences with the layer-solution or some other advice?

Comment: Is this a question about security or about UI? Sounds like this may be better suited for https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You are choosing between rare but intricately crafted content vs. rather simple but easily and massively contributed.

The first option sets high entry barrier for editing. That's a way when selected professional editors work on not so frequently published pages.

The second option is what is actually being used by wiki engines. The entry barrier is next to nothing which encourages and enables much more contributions from readers.